# Xcode error at runtime

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

You can see the error in the image.

I don't even know what these errors mean, it was working fine before I updated Xcode for the iOS 6 update.  I've done a few things to try and fix it such as change the target OS and do a Clean, but that has not worked.

I get the error after the app successfully is built and pushed to the device.

[image]

Comment: `argc` is the number of arguments passed to your binary and `argv` is an array of strings containing the parameters

Comment: You are showing error that has propagated to your main doesn't give much information. Can you give more information on when it's happening and what did you do to debug it.

Comment: You are trying to set a view for UIApplication, but UIApplication has no view. Maybe you have a wrong connection in the xib or storyboard.

Comment: The error is at runtime, not at compile time: the title of your question is confusing (please edit)

Comment: phix I don't think so, I've set my Main Interface to my view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application crashed at runtime, because there was an exception.

The exception is written in your console log. We can see it in your capture:

> `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x...> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'`

This means that somewhere in your application, you tried to set the "view" property of an object of type `UIApplication`, but `UIApplication` does not have any `view` property, so this crashes.

This is very likely that **in your MainWindow.xib file, you connected a `view` IBOutlet to an object of type `UIApplication`**, but this binding of your outlet is invalid because the outlet does not exist anymore.

*(maybe you added the outlet at a given time, and binded/connected it in IB, and then removed it in your code, or maybe you binded the IBOutlet then changed the class of your object so the new class does not have the same outlets at all, whatever the outlet is now binded to a non-existant property in your XIB and that generates the crash)*

**To fix this**, open your XIB file in interface builder and remove this invalid connection to your now non-existant outlet, and your exception should go away.

Answer (score 3):

It means your program crashed. The error is in that box in the corner right. I can't see the whole error message, but it has something to do with key-value coding.

It might be the simple fact that you're running a slightly outdated version of your program. Delete it from the simulator or your device, clean and re-build your project, and let Xcode re-copy it over.

Comment: I've updated the picture.  I've also done a delete of the app on the device and simulator and re-built it.  That had no effect.